# Visual Studio could not launch code.exe unexpected error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2022

Within Visual Studio, when I try to right click a file and choose "Open With..." then choose Visual Studio Code, I get the error:

`Visual Studio could not launch code.exe unexpected error`

Answer (score 0):

I had to right-click the file again, click "Open with..." and this time remove the option to open with Visual Studio Code and re-add it.